# Error al tratar conexión entre sql server y proyecto netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

Al momento de hacer la conexión me arroja un error de la ruta, este es el error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Universidad;user=sa;password=Jsilva02;

Este es mi código:

public class Conexion {

```
public static Connection getConexion() {
    String conexionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
            + "database=Universidad;"
            + "user=sa;"
            + "password=Jsilva02;";
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conexionUrl);
        return con;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        return null;

    }

}
```

}

pensé que era el TCP/IP pero esta habilitado, pense que era el jar del jdk pero tambien lo tengo correcto y la verdad no se que más hacer

Comment: ¿`databaseName`? Por cierto, la conexión es entre SQL Server y _Java_.

Comment: Mil disculpas pero no entendí tu pregunta

Comment: En tu string de conexión tenés `database=***`, por eso pregunto: ¿es `database` o `databaseName`?

Answer (score 1):

El error no indica un "error en la ruta", en realidad indica:

> No se encontró un conductor apropiado

Debes asegurar [descargar el driver para SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) y registrar el .jar a tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de esto revisa si el Driver funciona correctamente

```
try { 
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");     
       System.out.println("Driver funciona correctamente!."); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
}
```